# Refreshing the browser produces a WSGI "/null" as last GET request. Why the "null" string in the URL?

Tags: python, wsgi

In a Python WSGI app
I add a `print(environ['PATH_INFO'])` 
in the WSGI entry point `def wsgi(self,environ,start_response)`.

After a refresh of the browser,
there is this "/null" or "/en/null" URL `GET` request.
I don't know why it is there.

```
/en/content
/static/960.css
/static/main.css
/static/pygments.css
/en/null
```

or

```
/
/static/960.css
/static/main.css
/static/pygments.css
/null
```

There is no HTTP request from my javascript. So it must come from outside my app.

- Could someone point me to a spec which explains this "null" string?
- If this is expected, how should one handle the URL with the "null" string?

https://www.ietf.org/rfc/rfc2616.txt mentions `null`, but meaning "without value".
I mean the actual "null" string in the URL.

https://www.python.org/dev/peps/pep-0333/ does not mention a `null`.

Comment: Are you using a proxy?  Also what OS are you on? (I assume this is a local dev server)

Comment: I'm on Linux and testing my app with `WSGIRefSever` on the same machine.